# What is the end credits song in Borderlands?

Tags: borderlands, game-music-identification

I just beat the last boss in Borderlands, but then a friend skipped the end song. It was sounding pretty cool, so I was wondering what it was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"No Heaven" by DJ Champion.  And it *is* a pretty neat song.  I've been meaning to download (legally) a copy for a while now!

Answer (score 4):

If you are wanting to buy No Heaven by DJ Champion, it is not in the Borderlands soundtrack which is just the in game background music. Nor is the title song "Ain't No Rest For The Wicked" by Cage The Elephant.